# How can I see what each key does in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I'm looking for something like "M-x describe-key" in emacs.

I see `Help > Default Keymap Reference` and `Settings > Keymap` but both of these are grouped and sorted by topic. I want something grouped and sorted by key.

The obvious answer of just pressing the key isn't always helpful. For example, when I press F11, I get a little checkbox in the gutter, but there's no tooltip and I have no idea what it might signify.

I'll happily upvote the answer to that particular question, but I'm really looking for a live reference. I guess if there isn't one, I'll probably take a stab at parsing the config file myself, but I'm hoping someone already has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the jetbrains website I found this:

[Official shortcut reference](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/keyboard-shortcuts-reference.html)

Its a bit complex but there is almost everything on there you might need.
I know I have a simpler version downloaded on my computer somewhere at home, ill check on it and post it here later.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is new since you asked the question, but in Pycharm 1.2.1 you can go to `Setting > Keymap` and enter a shortcut filter:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ttoR.png (can't inline images as a newbie --sorry!)

Here you can enter up to 2 keys and get the resulting action.

It is still not grouped and sorted by key but at least you get an explanation for that particular key.