# pycharm find action from shortcut

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm has the action (command) 'Find Action'. Given an action name, it will report the shortcut for that action and the context where you should issue it, e.g. in the editing window. Think of this as action -> shortcut. It also has the useful plugin "Key Promoter", which will report the shortcut you could have used when you invoked a menu action. Finally you can search for an action given a shortcut (which is what I want) in the Settings > Keymap, button "Search by Shortcut" (or something like that). Think of this as shortcut -> action. Finally the question: Is there a pycharm command that let's me search shortcut -> action without burrowing down through the settings? I do this often enough that I'd like a fast solution. Thanks.

Comment: A variant of this question was asked using emacs as an analogy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149859/how-can-i-see-what-each-key-does-in-pycharm. Answer that question and you answer mine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid it's not possible without going to Keymap settings, [added a new feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99850) as I found myself missing this feature as well, please vote.

Comment: Issue applies to all jetbrains products, such as IntelliJ, RubyMine.

Comment: Well, there's the [Keymap exporter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7066-keymap-exporter) plugin, which JetBrains released in 2012.